# MudBlazor Autocomplete with Custom Object (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor's Autocomplete component for a drop down containing a list of custom objects. The following code works as expected, however the first time it loads I get the following System.NullReferenceException error once for every item in the list. After these errors the component works as expected. What am I missing here? Why is the user object null the first time around? Since the error hits once for every object in the list the object is not null. Is there another way to set this component up?

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <MudAutocomplete T="MailboxUser" Label="Select Forward From Mailbox" @bind-Value="SelectedForwardFrom" SearchFunc="@SearchUsers" ToStringFunc="user => user.DisplayName"
                             ResetValueOnEmptyText="false" />
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>


    private List<MailboxUser> ActiveForwards { get; set; }
    private List<MailboxUser> AllUsers { get; set; }
    private MailboxUser SelectedForwardFrom { get; set; }
    private MailboxUser SelectedForwardTo { get; set; }
    private bool SendToBoth { get; set; }
    private IOrderedEnumerable<MailboxUser> SortedUsers { get; set; }
    
    private string SelectedForwardFromString { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AllUsers = await PowerRun.GetAllUsersAsync();

        if (AllUsers != null)
        {
            SortedUsers = AllUsers.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
        }

        ActiveForwards = await PowerRun.GetActiveForwardsAsync();
    
    }


    private async Task<IEnumerable<MailboxUser>> SearchUsers(string value)
    {
    // if text is null or empty, show complete list
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return SortedUsers;
        }
        return SortedUsers.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Comment: I was intrigued as i got the same as you did in a test.  I went digging into the MudBlazor Source code to figure out what the problem was.   See my answer that is slightly different from yours.

Answer (score 3):

I went digging into the MudBlazor code. Turns out you need to account for a null as the initial value for the property `bind-Value` is bound to.  The control tries to apply `ToStringFunc` to a null T; if you don't code to handle nulls, bang!

This checks if item is null before trying to return item.Name.

```cs
item => item is null ? null : item.Name
```

Here's my one page demo that shows you how to do that.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <MudAutocomplete T=Country 
            Label="Select Country" 
            @bind-Value=selectedCountry 
            SearchFunc=this.FilterCountriesAsync 
            ToStringFunc=DisplayValue/>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

@code {
    private Country? selectedCountry;

    private Func<Country, string?> DisplayValue = item => item is null ? null : item.Name;

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> FilterCountriesAsync(string value)
    {
        // pretend to be a async api or Db call
        await Task.Yield();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return _countries.Where(item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower())) ?? _countries;

        return _countries;
    }

    private List<Country> _countries = new()
    {
       new Country("France"),
       new Country("Finland"),
       new Country("United Kingdom"),
       new Country("United States of America"),
    };

    public record Country(string Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the placeholder for the initial empty selection field was being passed to the "ToStringFunc", so using "user => user.DisplayName" would not work as the first user would be null. To fix this I removed "user => user.DisplayName" and replaced it with a function that checks for null.

```
<MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <MudAutocomplete T="MailboxUser" ToStringFunc="@(i => CombineDisplayNameAndEmail(i))" Label="Select Forward From Mailbox" @bind-Value="SelectedForwardFrom" SearchFunc="@SearchUsers"   ResetValueOnEmptyText="false" />
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>


    private string CombineDisplayNameAndEmail(MailboxUser user)
    {
        
        if (user != null)
        {
            return $"{user.DisplayName} ({user.PrimarySmtpAddress})";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Also worth noting if somebody stumbles across this in the future you can easily search multiple different properties. I updated my SearchUsers function to search both the display name and email address properties.

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<MailboxUser>> SearchUsers(string value)
    {
    // if text is null or empty, show complete list
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return SortedUsers;
        }
        return SortedUsers.Where(x => x.DisplayName.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || x.PrimarySmtpAddress.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
```